# No versus not in Japanese

Tags: grammar, word-choice

Is there a difference between no versus not in japanese, or is it just always いいえ？

Comment: The simple answer is, yes there is a difference. It's unclear what you're asking. You should edit your question to provide an example sentence or some more context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"not" is merely a way to express negation in English. In Japanese, this is usually expressed using different conjugations. It seems like you are a beginner, so this is a good place to start:
http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/negativeverbs